# how to convert this curl command to c# webrequest

Tags: c#, curl, webrequest

CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
CURLOPT_URL => 'http://vbypass.tech/bottele/',
CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.101 Safari/537.36 ',
CURLOPT_POST => 1,
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false, //
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query(array(
'apptoken' => $basic,
'md' => $md,
'mdm' => $mdm,

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with RestSharp and Newtonsoft libraries..

```
using RestSharp;
using Newtonsoft.Json;



var client = new RestClient("http://vbypass.tech");
            client.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.101 Safari/537.36";
            var request = new RestRequest("/bottele", Method.POST);
            var post = new { apptoken = "YOURAPPTOKEN", md = "MD", mdm = "MDM" };
            request.AddJsonBody(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(post));
            var response = client.Execute(request);
            if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
            }
```

var post = new { apptoken = "YOURAPPTOKEN", md = "MD", mdm = "MDM" };
fill api token values ​​and enjoy !